# Graalvm tool: native-image-configure not found

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

The link describes the usage of the tool `native-image-configure`
https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/CONFIGURE.md

I am not able to find this tool in Graalvm version 19.0.3.2 for JDK11

Where do i get this tool?

Comment: Here's an updated link that describes the use of that tool https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/BuildConfiguration/#the-native-image-configure-tool

However, the latest GraalVM (21.0.0.2.r11-grl) does not offer it. Running `native-image --macro:native-image-configure-launcher` produces error `Error: Unknown name in option specification: macro:native-image-configure-launcher`

Answer (score 1):

Actually it includes in the native-image package but not as a tool.

You can run it as a java program:

```
java --add-exports jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.common=ALL-UNNAMED \
         --add-exports jdk.internal.vm.ci/jdk.vm.ci.meta=ALL-UNNAMED \
         -cp /opt/graalvm-ce-java11-20.1.0/lib/graalvm/svm-agent.jar:/opt/graalvm-ce-java11-20.1.0/lib/svm/builder/svm.jar com/oracle/svm/configure/ConfigurationTool \
         generate --resource-input=resource-custom.json --reflect-input=reflect-custom.json --trace-input=trace-log.json --output-dir=./mockserver/native-configure
```

Answer (score 0):

JDK 11 is not supported with Graalvm version 19.0.3.2.
Please use GraalVM 19.3 with JDK 11.
you can download the same from below link:
https://www.graalvm.org/downloads/

If you are using EE then after installing GraalVM, you can download native image jar file and install it using:

```
gu intsall -F <jar>
```

for CE: 
download from 
https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/tag/vm-19.3.0.2 and than run gu like this

```
sudo $GRAALVM_HOME/bin/gu -L install ~/Downloads/native-image-installable-svm-java11-darwin-amd64-19.3.0.2.jar
```

Comment: i still get the same issue . with GraalVM Version 20.0.0 CE. Available tool options are:
    --tool:coverage
    --tool:lsp
    --tool:profiler
    --tool:chromeinspector
    --tool:agentscript

Comment: @Srikanth do you want to you use native-image?

Comment: @Srikanth you just have to run gu install native-image in GraalVM Version 20.0.0 CE version. I just downloaded it and its working